# Chrome Custom Tabs returning to wrong Intent

Tags: android, facebook, google-chrome, android-studio, chrome-custom-tabs

In my recent programmed Android App, I discovered a problem regarding Chrome Custom Tabs. I'm using Custom Tabs to open sites of different Social Media Platforms like Twitter, Twitch, YouTube, Instagram, Snapchat and Facebook.

I'm going to give you a quick overview of the Activities of my app so you can understand my problem:

DashboardActivity -> PostActivity -> opens Custom Tabs

When I use Custom Tabs to open a Twitter Page and I click on the Close-Button in the top I will be redirected to the PostActivity. This also happens on Twitter, YouTube, and the other platforms.

But when I open a Facebook page using Custom Tabs and I close the Tab I'm redirected to the DashboardActivity despite I use the same piece of code to start it as to start the other pages.

```
CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();

        switch (view.getId()) {

            case R.id.youtube_content_image: {

                //START YOUTUBE APP
                YouTubePost youtubePost = (YouTubePost) mPosts.get(position);
                String url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + youtubePost.getId();

                builder.setToolbarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.color_youtube));
                CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
                customTabsIntent.launchUrl(this, Uri.parse(url));

            }

            case R.id.instagram_content_image: {
                InstagramPost post = (InstagramPost) mPosts.get(position);

                builder.setToolbarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.color_instagram));
                CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
                customTabsIntent.launchUrl(this, Uri.parse(post.getWebLink()));
            }

            case R.id.snapchat_content_text: {
                SnapchatPost post = (SnapchatPost) mPosts.get(position);

                builder.setToolbarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.color_snapchat));
                CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
                customTabsIntent.launchUrl(this, Uri.parse(post.getSnapchatUrl()));

            }

            case R.id.facebook_content_text: {
                FacebookPost post = (FacebookPost) mPosts.get(position);
                String url = "https://www.facebook.com/" + post.getId();

                builder.setToolbarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.color_facebook));
                CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
                customTabsIntent.launchUrl(this, Uri.parse(url));

            }

            case R.id.twitter_content_text: {
                TwitterPost post = (TwitterPost) mPosts.get(position);

                String url = "https://twitter.com/" + mAccountHolder.getTwitterUsername() +"/status/" + post.getId();

                builder.setToolbarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.color_twitter));
                CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
                customTabsIntent.launchUrl(this, Uri.parse(url));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you see any errors on Logcat, before of after opening the Custom Tab?

Comment: On another note, the posted code is missing the break statements for each case. In Java, switch statements fall through if you don't break, which means that, all the cases bellow the first one to be matched are also executed. This may be generating unexpected errors.

Comment: @andreban OK. Look for both things

Comment: @andreban Yep. Somehow the breaks managed to solve it. Write your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as solved

Comment: Added as an answer. Did you manage to find anything on logcat? I'm curious about what was happening (memory issues forcing the Activity to close maybe?)

Comment: @andreban The problem was pretty easy. After the full facebook case statement the object was casted to TwitterPost what crashed the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posted code is missing the break statements for each case. In Java, switch statements fall through if you don't break, which means that, all the cases bellow the first one to be matched are also executed. This may be generating unexpected errors.